# How to build two images with different settings of a recipe in Yocto

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I'm using Yocto. I have two images with the same distro and the same machine and each image should contain the same package, but build with different settings.

For example, the config file *sshd_config* is part of the *opensshd* package, but I need a different set of *HostKeyAlgorithms* depending on the image. (Yes, I could use *Include,* but that's not the point of this question.)

How can I build two different flavours of the same package? One way would be to have a different distro for each image, but this wouldn't scale. My other idea is to use *local.conf* to change the build behaviour of the recipe and control the image content (and the difference between both) with the *local.conf.* But what's best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be different local.conf. You could do in it:

```
OVERRIDES:append = ":<something_that_will_distinguish_the_image>"
```

And then have in your `openssh_%.bbappend`

```
SRC_URI:append:<something_that_will_distinguish_the_image> = " file://different_config"
```

Reference: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.2/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-OVERRIDES